# In wordpress customizer div still showing even if I hid it with javascript

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, theme-options

I am loading a div in my single.php based on a setting in the customizer. It all works fine in the front-end as expected. But in the customizer that div is still showing even if the setting is unchecked previously. But the problem occurs only the first time. if I check the checkbox and uncheck again, the div hides as expected.
[image: first time I load the customizer, the is shown, even if it's previously unchecked]

Now another screenshot to show after I check the checkbox twice:
[image: the div hides after I check the checkbox twice]

I hope the question is clear now. Here are the relevant codes:

I'm showing author info in single.php with

```
<?php if ( isset($GLOBALS['wp_customize']) || get_theme_mod( '_themename_display_author_info', true) ) :
    get_template_part( '/template-parts/single/post-navigation' );
endif;?>
```

I have necessary js files included with:

```
function _themename_customize_preview_js () {
    wp_enqueue_script( '_themename-cutomize-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/js/customize-preview.js', array('customize-preview', 'jquery'), '1.0.0' , true );

}

add_action( 'customize_preview_init', '_themename_customize_preview_js' );
```

my /lib/customizer.php file:

```
$wp_customize->add_section('_themename_single_blog_options', array(
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Single Blog Options', '_themename' ),
        'description' => esc_html__( 'You can change single blog options from here.', '_themename' ),
        'active_callback' => '_themename_show_single_blog_section'
    ));

    //Author Info

    $wp_customize->add_setting('_themename_display_author_info', array(
        'default' => true,
        'transport' => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => '_themename_sanitize_checkbox'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('_themename_display_author_info', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Show Author Info', '_themename' ),
        'section' => '_themename_single_blog_options'
    ));
function _themename_sanitize_checkbox( $checked ) {
    return (isset($checked) && $checked === true) ? true : false;
}
```

My customize-preview.js:

```
wp.customize( '_themename_display_author_info', (value) => {
    value.bind( (to) => {
        if(to) {
            $('#author-info').show();
        } else {
            $('#author-info').hide();
        }
    } )
})
```

And finally my /template-parts/single/author.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Let's get author information first
 */
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$author_posts_number = get_the_author_posts();
$author_dispay = get_the_author();
$author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($author_id);
$author_description = get_the_author_meta('user_description');
$author_website = get_the_author_meta('user_url');
?>

<div id="author-info">

    <h2 class="screen-reader-text">
        <?php esc_attr_e( 'About the Author', '_themename'); ?>
    </h2>

    <div id="author-avatar">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $author_id, 100 ); //100 is the size of the avatar, in this case it's 100x100px ?>
    </div><!-- # avatar -->

    <div id="author-content">
        <!-- author name and url -->
        <?php if( $author_website) : ?>
            <h3>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $author_website ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html( $author_dispay ); ?></a>
            </h3>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h3>
                <?php echo esc_html( $author_dispay ); ?>
            </h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you already resolved the issue? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Unfortunately, NO. I'm totally stuck and don't really know what's the problem. In my customize-preview.js: I'm hiding the div if the checkbox value is false. it should work right?

If you find the solution, please post it here.

Comment: Yes that (JS) would work; however, if I'm not mistaken, you should also use CSS to visually hide the div (`#author-info`) if the theme mod is `false` (the checkbox is not checked). Something like `if ( ! get_theme_mod( '_themename_display_author_info', true ) ) echo '<style>#author-info { display: none; }</style>';`. And you can add that using the `wp_head` hook..

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

if anyone faces this in future: thanks to @SallyCJ i was able to solve the issue by adding css style to the customize_preview_init hook.
Here's the code:

```
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', function() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'cutomizer-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/js/customize-preview.js', array('customize-preview', 'jquery'), time() , true );

    if ( !get_theme_mod( '_themename_display_author_info', true ) ) :
        add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
            echo '<style>#author-info{display:none;}</style>';
        }  );
    endif;

} );
```